# Ionic Http failure during parsing when not in livereload or local

Tags: ionic3

Only when I compile my app `ionic cordova run android` I got this error

[image]

if I compile it with `--livereload` it doesn't happens, I'm using proxy to resolve the CORS problem

```
{
  "name": "gestor",
  "type": "ionic-angular",
  "integrations": {
    "cordova": {}
  },
  "proxies": [
    {
      "path": "/api",
      "proxyUrl": "https://gestor2.siacomsistemas.com.br/api"
    }
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was that for production I can't use the proxies so I needed to test when I'm creating the URL

```
    protected baseApi = "/api/";

    constructor(protected platform: Platform) {
        if (platform.is('cordova')) {
            this.baseApi = "https://gestor2.siacomsistemas.com.br/api/";
        }
    }
```

and the CORs issue was in my api server side, I'm using laravel and needed to create a CORs middleware

```
\\app\Http\Middleware\Cors.php

<?php

namespace App\Http\Middleware;

use Closure;


class Cors {

    public function handle($request, Closure $next)
    {
        return $next($request)
            ->header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*')
            ->header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'GET, POST, PUT, DELETE, OPTIONS')
            ->header('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'Content-Type, Accept, Authorization, X-Requested-With, XMLHttpRequest');
    }
}
```

and call it on my Kernel

```
\\app\Http\Kernel.php

    protected $middleware = [
        \Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Middleware\CheckForMaintenanceMode::class,
        \Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Middleware\ValidatePostSize::class,
        \App\Http\Middleware\TrimStrings::class,
        \Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Middleware\ConvertEmptyStringsToNull::class,
        \App\Http\Middleware\TrustProxies::class,
        \App\Http\Middleware\HttpsProtocol::class,
        \App\Http\Middleware\Cors::class,
    ];
```